# Passing custom object to RunWorkerCompleted event in case of an exception

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

My Console App uses `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` for threading purposes:

```
System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();

backgroundWorker.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
     ReportStatus(worker, status, result, e);
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(worker);
```

As you can see that I am passing "worker" as an argument inside RunWorkerAsync.

What I am trying to achieve is that if there is an exception inside ReportStatus method I need the same "worker" object so that I can perform some operation (Call a service to notify that workers exception)

```
private void ReportStatus(Worker worker, Status status, WorkResult result,System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs arg)
{
    var proxy = new PreparationServiceProxy(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(PreparationEngineState.ServiceAddress));
    try
    {
        proxy.ReportStatus(worker, status, result);
        proxy.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        arg.Result = worker;
        proxy.Abort();
        throw;
    }
}
```

In my exception block (I am not sure if this is the correct way!) I am assigning the worker to the Result so that I can get the same worker back when the RunWorkerCompleted method (backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted) is executed :

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Worker worker = e.Result as Worker; // At this point I get an exception!
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but the basic question is that inside "backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted" I get an exception when I try to convert my argument back to the worker object:

Comment: Since I am throwing the exception (for it to bubble up to backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted) , the exception I get is : "An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you re-threw the exception.  `BackgroundWorker` sees that as an exception unhandled by the `DoWork` handler and re-throws it back on the other thread when you get the `Result` value.

If you don't want it to do that, remove the `throw` in your catch in the `DoWork` handler.

if you passed the worker object into the `BackgroundWorker`, why don't use just use what you passed in in an exception handler wrapping the call to `Result` or in the block that tests `Error`? e.g.:

```
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            worker.DoSomething(); // no access of Result
        }
```

Comment: Removing the throw does work and I do get the worker object back, but in that case the e.Error is null

Comment: Yeah, if you want to use the Worker in Result, don't throw.  If you *do* want to use Error, throw and don't set the Result to worker...

Comment: then how do I pass the worker object to "backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted" in case of an exception? :)

Comment: Well, you can only have one "result".  if the result you want is an exception/Error then that's the only result.  If you wanted to support Error you could use a "shared" worker object contained in the class that invokes `BackgroundWorker`.  The way you've described "worker" it's not a "result" and seems out of place when used in `Result`.  I would just code failures in the form class and deal with the worker there.

Comment: Creating a custom exception wrapper (also described below by @Philipp) was the way to go ! :)

Answer (score 2):

.NET does NOT consider that Async Operation might have some result if an Error happened. That's why you will have pass it some other way.

I would recommend to implement custom exception class:

```
public class WorkerException:ApplicationException
{
    public WorkerException(Worker worker,Exception innerException):base(null,innerException)
    { Worker = worker; }

    public Worker Worker
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And wrap you exception accordingly:

```
private void ReportStatus(Worker worker, Status status, WorkResult result,System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs arg)
{
    var proxy = new PreparationServiceProxy(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(PreparationEngineState.ServiceAddress));
    try
    {
        proxy.ReportStatus(worker, status, result);
        proxy.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        arg.Result = worker;
        proxy.Abort();
        throw new WorkerException(worker,exception);
    }
}
```

In this case you will be able to retrieve Worker of exception, casting Error to WorkerException:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Error is WorkerException)
    {
        Worker worker = ((WorkerException)e.Error).Worker; // At this point I get an exception!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` contains a `UserState` property which (I think) should be a reference to the same object that you passed to the `RunWorkerAsync` method.  (It should also be in the `DoWorkEventArgs` as the `Argument` property.)

You'll need to experiment to confirm that this `UserState` is the right object (cast it `as Worker`) and that it is valid even when the `DoWork` handler threw an exception, but I think that could be what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry but in the case of an exception the UserState is null :(

Comment: Hmmm, that's disappointing of them because there should be a way (without extra hoops and fully understanding threadsafe multithreaded programming to track it yourself) to identify what background operation threw an error--although I suppose there can never be more than one outstanding for the same BackgroundWorker instance.  You could, of course, assign the caught exception as the result and test for that as the error case (allowing UserState to then be set to the worker, right?), but that isn't necessarily an ideal approach all around.